# Validation on XHTML + RDFa with iFrame on Drupal 7

Tags: validation, drupal, xhtml

A website I'm currently designing needs to pass W3C's Markup Validation.  We're using Drupal 7 which forces our theme to be in XHTML + RDFa. We are using Google Maps which requires an iFrame in turn causing me grief.

> element "iframe" undefined

Anyone have any ideas how I can get around this validation test?  Would it be wise to replace the iframe with Google Maps javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The tyranny of validation is not always a good thing. If you have to use a doctype/schema that doesn't allow `<iframe>` and also a service that requires `<iframe>` then you're stuck.

The nonsense is that (a) iframe works just great cross-browser and (b) since the XHTML 1.x specs were determined `<iframe>` has gained a new lease of life in HTML5, where it is a fully valid element with lots of new functionality.

Also, it's almost certain that you're serving your pages with a text/html content type, which means that browsers aren't treating your markup in the same way as the validator, and therefore the results of the validator are essentially futile.

If, regardless, you really *have* to conform, then you will have to not use `<iframe>`.

All that said, I don't think it is necessary to use `<iframe>` with Google Maps. One option may be to use an `<object>` instead. But I am using Google Maps (V2 JavaScript API) without either, just with the map element embedded directly in the container page. Seems to work fine.

I'm not using Drupal 7, though. I don't know what extra constraints that may be applying.

Answer (score 0):

If the `<iframe>` tag is added from JavaScript code, then the site would pass the validation.
I am not sure, too, that when using the Google Maps JavaScript is necessary to use that HTML tag.

Answer (score 0):

This will be work

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('#iframe').after('<iframe src="url" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" overflow:hidden; width:400px; height: 70px;"></iframe>');
});
</script>
```